# How can I associate students to the school through two levels (courses and course sections) in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models, rails-3.1

A school has many courses.  A course has many sections.  A student enrolls in a section of a course.  I want to be able to find all the students at the school.

```
Class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :sections, :through => courses
  has_many :students, :through => courses, :through => sections, :through => enrollments
end

Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :sections
  has_many :students, :through => sections, :through => enrollment
end

Class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :students, :through => enrollment
end

Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections, :through => enrollment
  has_many :courses, :through => sections, :through => enrollment
  has_many :schools, :through => courses, :through => sections, :through => enrollment
end
```

enrollment is just a table with the section id and student id when a student enrolls in that section of the course.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you right, but I would do a slightly different set of relations:
school has many courses, course has many sections, section has many students through enrollment.
That would lead to the following models:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, :through => :enrollment
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, :through => :enrollment
end
```

That would allow to properly reference all kinds of data. For example, I would like to see all students of all sections of all courses of the first school. I would then use something like this: `School.first.courses.map(&:sections).flatten.map(&:students).flatten`. I am sure you would be able to elaborate this further.